# Google Analytics API: Report dimensions and metrics are null

Tags: google-analytics

I am using the sample code from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php, and printResults is failing because $dimensionHeaders and $dimensions are null

Also, it seems to only work if "ga:" is prepended to the view ID provided by google analytics admin\view\view settings\view ID. Is that correct, or am I using the wrong view ID?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the correct View ID is what the Google Analytics admin interface is in:

```
Admin --> View --> View settings --> View ID
```

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google's sample code is missing this key bit in getReport() underneath the line: $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();

```
   //Create the Dimensions object.
   $browser = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
   $browser->setName("ga:browser");
   $request->setDimensions(array($browser));
```